# Why all cookie data removed on browser close on ios safari

Tags: javascript, ios, cookies, safari, mobile-safari

I am working on a cookie based mobile web application.Its working fine on pc (firefox,chrome and safari).Its also working well on mobile chrome browser on my Iphone5 IOS 8.1.2.But the problem occurs on safari of my iphone.when I close my safari browser all cookie data removes.But when I refresh the page it doesn't remove cookie data.Why all cookie data removed during browser close (only on mobile safari).I am stuck on it for 2 days.

Comment: Is Safari in private mode? What is the cookie policy in Safari settings?

Comment: No,My safari isn't in private mode, and cookie policy is "always allow"